# Tutorial for debugging RoR from the shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, hosting

I am new to RoR and I am experiencing the `500 server error` for a long time without success. 
I need someone tell me (or link to) how to debug RoR apps from the shell.

My application is [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and I am trying to host it at [hostmonster](http://www.hostmonster.com) who tuns rails version 2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is look in your log/production.log file in your live app directory. That will contain all the relevant details about your error.

There are certain - very useful - plugins ([exception_notification](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification) for example) which will email details about errors to you as they occur.

Comment: It ends before logging anything

Comment: Ok, in that case you will need your web server logs (check your Apache error log if your app is running behind Apache, for example)

Answer (score 2):

1. please check your database.yml.
2. see log: log/development.log
3. you can debug issue: http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html

hope helpful with you!

Answer (score 1):

The latest Redmine trunk runs on Rails 2.3.5

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/config/environment.rb

which could be causing you problems. Try setting RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' in your environment.rb file... although you may find other bugs crop up!